# Debian Ports GPG key error when running apt update

Tags: gpg

When I run on my home server `apt update` I get:

```
Hit:1 http://ftp.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease
Get:2 http://ftp.ports.debian.org/debian-ports unstable InRelease [55.3 kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.ports.debian.org/debian-ports unreleased InRelease [56.6 kB]
Ign:4 https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Debian_9.0  InRelease
Hit:5 https://download.owncloud.org/download/repositories/stable/Debian_9.0  Release
Err:2 http://ftp.ports.debian.org/debian-ports unstable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A88D659DCB811BB
Err:3 http://ftp.ports.debian.org/debian-ports unreleased InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A88D659DCB811BB
Fetched 112 kB in 3s (33.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
765 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ftp.ports.debian.org/debian-ports unstable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A88D659DCB811BB
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://ftp.ports.debian.org/debian-ports unreleased InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A88D659DCB811BB
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.ports.debian.org/debian-ports/dists/unstable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A88D659DCB811BB
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.ports.debian.org/debian-ports/dists/unreleased/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A88D659DCB811BB
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

According to other questions I should fix using:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 5A88D659DCB811BB
```

But I get this error:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.fTPsBznh8Q/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 5A88D659DCB811BB
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
```

How can I fix this issue?

**Edit**
Tried with Debian as suggested in comment:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyring.debian.org --recv-keys 5A88D659DCB811BB
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.HQ0bpUZIjb/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyring.debian.org --recv-keys 5A88D659DCB811BB
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Comment: dunno why you'd expect ubuntu's keyserver to have debian keys.  maybe try `keyring.debian.org` instead.   see also https://www.ports.debian.org/ but the newest key they mention there is from 2018.

Comment: Did you read the "Package authentication" section from the manual? https://www.ports.debian.org/archive

Comment: @cas thanks for your input, I've added the result to the question

Comment: @Braiam
Your suggestion worked perfectly!
I used wget -O - https://www.ports.debian.org/archive_2021.key | apt-key add -